# Black box testing of webpages in python

Tags: python, http, testing, web

Does anyone know of any APIs that i could use to test my website from a blackbox point of view.

I would need to enter some text into a text box and extract the corresponding output for multiple cases on the same page.

I would like to perform a load and stress test on this website.

Pardon my incorrect jargon if there is any as i am extremely new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is an extremely powerful tool for testing web applications. Its primary function is to act as a browser and carry out unit tests, so it may be useful to you for doing things like entering text into a text box and extracting the corresponding output for multiple cases.

You can read more about Selenium [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Also python bindings exist, which you can read about [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)

As far as stress testing goes, take a look at this question posted on stack overflow [best way to stress test a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340564/best-way-to-stress-test-a-website)